# REST API POST works in curl but not in python

Tags: python-3.x, rest, urllib3

The service is a .net based service. Here is the python code

```
    URL = 'http://vp-testprocessor-service-bdp-dev.dev.xxxxxxxxxxxxxx.com/api/testprocessor/v1/testprocessors/requests'
    headers = {'Authorization': 'Bearer 00000000-0000-0000-adb2-3087bcbcdaf7',
               'Accept': 'applicaiton/json',
               'Content-Type': 'audio/x-wav;type=alaw;bit=16;rate=8000;channels=1',
               'User-Agent': 'Mozilla/5.0 AppleWebkit/537.36 Chrome/41.0.2272.101 Safari/537.36'}
    session = requests.Session()
    with open(input_file, 'rb') as fd:
      data = fd.read()
    request = requests.Request('POST', url, data = data, headers = headers)
    prepped = session.prepare_request(request)
    response = session.send(prepped, allow_redirects=False)
```

This is the output from python3.

```
    DEBUG:urllib3.connectionpool:06-13 07:59 Starting new HTTP connection (1): vp-testprocessor-service-bdp-dev.dev.xxxxxxxxxxxxxx.com
    DEBUG:urllib3.connectionpool:06-13 07:59 http://vp-testprocessor-service-bdp-dev.dev.xxxxxxxxxxxxxx.com:80 "POST /api/testprocessor/v1/testprocessors/requests HTTP/1.1" 400 0
```

This is the corresponding command in curl

```
    curl -X POST -i http://vp-testprocessor-service-bdp-dev.dev.xxxxxxxxxxxxxx.com/api/testprocessor/v1/testprocessors/requests -H "Accept:application/json" -H "Content-Type:audio/x-wav;type=alaw;bit=16;rate=8000;channels=1" -H "Authorization:Bearer 00000000-0000-0000-adb2-3087bcbcdaf7" --data-binary @test.WAV
```

The response is the response as expected:

```
    HTTP/1.1 202 Accepted
    Transfer-Encoding: chunked
    Content-Type: application/json; charset=utf-8
    Location: v1/testprocessors/requests/cjid8zvy905sd015mqzhk3tex
    Vary: Accept
    Server: nginx/1.13.9
    Set-Cookie: ApplicationGatewayAffinity=aec8bf4924904624c014f771c7c7d5052d5ca7537afccc9caa42d74a1f7e0023;Path=/;Domain=vp-testprocessor-service-bdp-dev.dev.xxxxxxxxxxxxxx.com
    Date: Wed, 13 Jun 2018 15:06:11 GMT

    {"status":"created","id":"cjid8zvy905sd015mqzhk3tex",...}
```

This is the wireshark trace for python request:

```
    1   0.000000000 192.168.0.75    55.555.555.555  TCP 74  38418 → 80 [SYN] Seq=0 Win=29200 Len=0 MSS=1460 SACK_PERM=1 TSval=2153419701 TSecr=0 WS=128
    2   0.101349932 55.555.555.555  192.168.0.75    TCP 74  80 → 38418 [SYN, ACK] Seq=0 Ack=1 Win=8192 Len=0 MSS=1440 WS=256 SACK_PERM=1 TSval=1248614227 TSecr=2153419701
    3   0.101404983 192.168.0.75    55.555.555.555  TCP 66  38418 → 80 [ACK] Seq=1 Ack=1 Win=29312 Len=0 TSval=2153419803 TSecr=1248614227
    4   0.101499143 192.168.0.75    55.555.555.555  TCP 499 38418 → 80 [PSH, ACK] Seq=1 Ack=1 Win=29312 Len=433 TSval=2153419803 TSecr=1248614227 [TCP segment of a reassembled PDU]
    5   0.101595314 192.168.0.75    55.555.555.555  HTTP    256 POST /api/testprocessor/v1/testprocessors/requests HTTP/1.1  (audio/x-wav)
    6   0.219204806 55.555.555.555  192.168.0.75    TCP 66  80 → 38418 [ACK] Seq=1 Ack=624 Win=263424 Len=0 TSval=1248614344 TSecr=2153419803
    7   0.232013694 55.555.555.555  192.168.0.75    HTTP    347 HTTP/1.1 400 Bad Request
```

This is the corresponding trace for curl request

```
    1   0.000000000 192.168.0.75    55.555.555.555  TCP 74  38400 → 80 [SYN] Seq=0 Win=29200 Len=0 MSS=1460 SACK_PERM=1 TSval=2153267280 TSecr=0 WS=128
    2   0.102793917 55.555.555.555  192.168.0.75    TCP 74  80 → 38400 [SYN, ACK] Seq=0 Ack=1 Win=8192 Len=0 MSS=1440 WS=256 SACK_PERM=1 TSval=1248461807 TSecr=2153267280
    3   0.102863788 192.168.0.75    55.555.555.555  TCP 66  38400 → 80 [ACK] Seq=1 Ack=1 Win=29312 Len=0 TSval=2153267383 TSecr=1248461807
    4   0.102977867 192.168.0.75    55.555.555.555  HTTP    576 POST /api/testprocessor/v1/testprocessors/requests HTTP/1.1  (audio/x-wav)
    5   0.273885394 55.555.555.555  192.168.0.75    TCP 66  80 → 38400 [ACK] Seq=1 Ack=511 Win=263424 Len=0 TSval=1248461978 TSecr=2153267383
    6   0.601893345 55.555.555.555  192.168.0.75    TCP 613 80 → 38400 [PSH, ACK] Seq=1 Ack=511 Win=263424 Len=547 TSval=1248462306 TSecr=2153267383 [TCP segment of a reassembled PDU]
    7   0.601961170 192.168.0.75    55.555.555.555  TCP 66  38400 → 80 [ACK] Seq=511 Ack=548 Win=30336 Len=0 TSval=2153267882 TSecr=1248462306
    8   0.601975534 55.555.555.555  192.168.0.75    HTTP    71  HTTP/1.1 202 Accepted  (application/json)
```

I have a couple of questions, 
1. is there a way to get more debug information from urllib3?
2. What can I do to mimic curl's behavior?
3. What information can I generate to help debug the server end?

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

I see the typo in my header, should have been 'Accept':'application/json' in my python code instead of 'Accept':'applicaiton/json'